# Navigation Bar Appearance barTintColor alpha component

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, translucency

I'm trying to add some transparency to my `NavigationBar` without any success. Within my `AppDelegate's` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, I have the following lines of code:

```
let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navigationBarAppearance.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
navigationBarAppearance.translucent = true
```

But no mater what the alpha component is, the transparency does not change. I have even attempted to use a color `UIImage`:

```
let colorImage = UIImage.imageFromColor(UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2), frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 340, height: 64))
navigationBarAppearance.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

That method alos doe not change the transparency of the navigation bar. Within a view controller I attempted:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0.2
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

And still no luck. Can anyone help me figure out how I can add transparency to my navigation bar?

Comment: Navigation bar magic. Doubt the developers know, what behind it.

Answer (score 12):

Here you go man. Just follow these steps

First make a extension class. Add just a new empty swift file and name it as **UIImageExtension** or whatever you feel like

Write the following code in that extension

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
extension UIImage{
    static func imageFromColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)

    // create a 1 by 1 pixel context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image

    }
}
```

Now go to your ViewController class and write the following code and play with **alpha**. Thats it.

```
let image = UIImage.imageFromColor(UIColor(red: 0.071, green: 0.071, blue: 0.922, alpha: 0.2))
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .Default
```

> **For Swift 3.0**

```
import Foundation
import Foundation
import UIKit
extension UIImage{
    static func imageFromColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)

        // create a 1 by 1 pixel context
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!

    }
}
```

**USAGE**

```
let image = UIImage.imageFromColor(color: UIColor(red: 0.071, green: 0.071, blue: 0.922, alpha: 0.2))
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
```

I also made a sample. Have a look. Sample is in Swift 2.x version
https://github.com/RajanMaheshwari/TransparentNav

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:**
Just changed the Navigation Bar to translucent and it worked
[image]

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: thanks, your solution works great! I'm using it to change the opacity of my navigation bar based on the amount of scrolling. The only issue I have now is that after I reach a certain scrolling threshold, I'm trying to make my navigation bar opaque again by setting the isTranslucent property back to false. Unfortunately, when I do this, my content jumps. Do you know what might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

In the last example you've changed the *tintColor*, not the *barTintColor*. 
Anyways, this three lines should work:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0.2
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

But remember that it will change the bar for the ***whole*** navigation controller, so you have to think about it when going back from that view controller.

Comment: The alpha component still doesn't have any effect. I can change it to 0.0 and it appears the same as when it's 0.2 or even 1.0.

Comment: It works on sample project so you might check if you have the navigationController (isn't nil) or maybe check if it is done on the main thread (you could try doing it in viewDidLoad)